# how to install custom made language pack in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, language

I just found a language pack in zip format which contains

```
composer.json
language.xml
registration.php
zh_CN.csv
LICENSE
README.md
```

I'm going to edit the csv inside , but i don't know how to install it, anyone knows?

e.g where should i upload? what command should i run?

Comment: I also face same problem after search various site may be app/i18n/Magento/ku_IQ/composer.json    but no luck yet to add local option , may check my link if get solution update me  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220119/how-can-i-add-new-language-in-magento-2-admin-panel-locale-options/220590#220590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the contents of zip in `app/i18n` in your magento root directory and set the locale of the store to your specified language (chinese in your case) from `Stores->Configuration->General->Locale Options` .Then run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_CN
```

Comment: i've ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_Hans_CN
but nothing was changed in frontend / backend, i've already set the locale to   zh_Hans_CN, any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me that you've edited the code in zip folder so make sure you've edited the things right by checking your code according to this answer ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067460/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-magento-2